# Integrate $\int x^2\sqrt{x-2}\,dx$ without integration by parts.

Tags: integration

> Integrate $$\int x^2\sqrt{x-2}\,dx.$$

Any ideas how I may approach this problem? We haven’t learned integration by parts

Comment: Substitute $u=x-2$.

Comment: Integration by parts wouldn't necessarily help you (you'd still have to do $u=x-2$ at some point).

Answer (score 1):

Render $u=\sqrt{x-2}$, then $x=u^2+2,dx=(2u)du$.  Then you just integrate the resulting polynomial in $u$.